# How to ask turtles which represent x% of Stock die?

Tags: netlogo, die

I am new to Netlogo my cas is as follows :
I have 100 turtles , turtles have two variables height and width, from height I can calculate  the stock. I know how to make asking x% of the turtles to die randomly ,  to ask the turtles have definite value smaller or larger to die; or to remove 30 % of stock.

but the case I have is a bit different , I want to remove 15 % of the stock from turtles has the least height values,in other words I want to ask turtles which have the least height values to die  So that the number of dead turtles represents 15 % of stock regardless of number.

Any hint or help ? I tried to do the following but I know that did not work:

```
turtles-own [ sh sto  ]
Globals [Stock death_severity]
to setup
  ca
  crt  100 [
    initialize_ITGM
    set sto   1.5 * sh + random 50
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
to go
  cal-stock
  remove-turtles
end
to cal-Stock
  set stock sum [sto] of turtles
end

to remove-turtles
if death_severity = "light_severity" [
  ask turtles with-min [sh] [die]
  set stock 0.20 * (Stock)]
end

to initialize_ITGM
  set sh  random-float 2   
end
```

Answer (score 3):

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#min-n-of

```
ask min-n-of (0.15 * count turtles) turtles [sh] [die]
```